# Javascript call() function - extra parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm reading `Javascript: The Definitive Guide 6th Edition`. It teaches ECMAscript 5.  Anyway, it doesn't explain certain things thoroughly, like the call() function for example. This is about the extent of the book's definition:

Any arguments to call() after the first invocation context argument are the values that are passed to the function that is invoked. For example, to pass two numbers to the function f() and invoke it as if it were a method of the object o, you could use code like this:

```
f.call(o, 1, 2);
```

In the next section the author builds a `map` function. I've been studying Ruby so I know how map works.  My question is about the implementation using the call() function.  It looks like this:

```
    var map = function(a,f, o) {                     
      var results = [];
      for(var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in a) 
          results[i] = f.call(o || null, a[i], i, a);
        }
        return results;
    };
```

It then defines a square function and puts map to use:

```
  function square(x){
    return x*x;
  }

  var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

  var results = map(array, square);
```

What is the purpose of the `i`, and `a` parameters in the call() function?  If I remove them I get the same results.

Comment: There's no requirement that all parameters be formally defined for the arguments that will be passed to them. If you know that the anonymous function you're passing has no use for the last two args, you don't need to define them in your function. They're still there and can be accessed via the `arguments` object, or you can formally define them in the parameter list. `function square(x, i, array) {...` In other words, there are 3 values being passed, and it's up to you if (and how) you want to access them.

Comment: ...this behavior isn't unique to `.call()`. The only difference between a normal function invocation and one using `.call()` is that with `.call()`, the first argument sets the `this` value of the function being called, and then the subsequent arguments are shifted over and become the typical arguments passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function.call allows you to call a function as though it were a method attached to an object.

What this means is you can have a function that is defined somewhere unrelated to an object, and then you can call that function as though it was a part of that object.  This is a long way of saying that when you use Function.call, you are telling the JS engine to use the first parameter whenever you use 'this' inside the function.

So:

```
function set_field_value(name, value) { 
    // do stuff 
    this[name] = value;
}
```

makes no sense by itself, because the special variable 'this' is not set to anything (meaningful)
But, if you use call, you can set it to whatever you want:

```
// if my_object = some object:
set_field_value.call(my_object, 'firstname', 'bob');
console.log(my_object.firstname); // prints 'bob'
```

The only important argument to call is the first one, (in the above case, my_object) because the first argument becomes 'this' inside the function.  The rest of the arguments are passed 'as is' to the function.

So - in your example, the i and a arguments are there to make the map function look like other map functions, which provide the array (a) and index (i) that are being worked on.

Hope that helps,

Jay

PS - I strongly recommend the book 'Javascript: the good parts' - it makes a lot more sense than the definitive guide.

Comment: In my example parameter o is null...so then what object is square called on?

Comment: It's a bit confusing at first.  square is a function, so it is executed.  It's not 'called on' anything.  Method invocation, whether via the normal obj.square() syntax or square.call(obj); syntax is essentially simply setting 'this' inside the function to the obj provided and then executing the function. When the obj provided is undefined, 'this' is either unset (in strict mode) or more commonly set to the global object.  In your case, this is never used, so it doesn't matter that it is unset.  Bugs often occur if this _is_ used and the obj is null, as it winds up modifying the global object.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.map` [is defined](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19) to pass the index and the array to the callback, just in case you need them. For example, instead of `square(x)`, you could use `Math.pow(base, exponent)`:

```
var results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(Math.pow);
console.log(results); // [1, 2, 9, 64, 625]
```

This `map` behaves in the same way. You don’t have to use the arguments if you don’t need them in a particular case.

Answer (score 0):

`f.call` in this example equals to `square.call`, and square requires only one parameter(`x`), so `i` and `a` are totally redundant here (and not used). Only `a[i]` is used by the function.

However, since you can pass in any function you want as the second parameter of the map function, chances are there will be another function instead of `square` coming up in the book, and that function would require those additional two parameters as well. Or you can make one example yourself to try it.

```
function threeParams(a, b, c) {
    return [a, b, c]; // simply puts the three parameters in an array and returns it
}
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var results = map(array, threeParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main confusion is not really about the `call` method. It's more about how javascript treats function arguments.

Forget about `call` for a moment and let's look at a regular function to minimize the number of things under consideration.

In javascript, functions are allowed to be called with more arguments than is specified. This is not considered an error. The arguments may be accessed via the `arguments` object:

```
function foo (arg1) {
    alert('second argument is: ' + arguments[1]);
}

foo('hello','world'); // this is not an error
```

Javascript also allows functions to be called with fewer arguments than specified. Again, this is not considered an error. The unpassed arguments are simply given the value `undefined`:

```
function foo (arg1,arg2, arg3) {
    alert('third argument is: ' + arg3);
}

foo('hello'); // this is not an error
```

That's all there is to it. When the function passed to `map()` is defined to accept one argument but `map()` calls it with three the remaining two arguments are essentially ignored.